# Update SQL query logic

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I have a table like below

```
TranId  SupplyType  SuppliedDate    ConsecutiveManualCount
1       A           05-Jan-12        0
2       A           05-Feb-12        0
3       M           07-Mar-12        0
4       M           07-Apr-12        0
5       A           08-May-12        0
6       M           07-Jun-12        0
7       M           08-Aug-12        0
8       M           06-Sep-12        0
9       A           07-Oct-12        0
```

I need to write an update query to update the consecutive manual count column as below.

```
TranId  SupplyType  SuppliedDate    ConsecutiveManualCount
1       A           05-Jan-12        0
2       A           05-Feb-12        0
3       M           07-Mar-12        1
4       M           07-Apr-12        2
5       A           08-May-12        0
6       M           07-Jun-12        1
7       M           08-Aug-12        1
8       M           06-Sep-12        2
9       A           07-Oct-12        0
```

The logic is like for every consecutive manual supply type "M" update the count accordingly. Whenever the supply type is automated that is SupplyType="A" reset the count to 0. Also while calculating the count, supplied date should be considered. For the TranId=8 the count is 2 instead of 3 because there is no supply on July 2012.

Can someone help me with the query for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using window functions.  The following uses `lag()` to determine when groups start, a cumulative sum to define the groups, and `row_number()` to do the final enumeration:

```
select t.*,
       (case when supplyType = 'M'
             then row_number() over (partition by grp, supplyType order by tranid)
             else 0
        end) as ConsecutiveManualCount
from (select t.*, sum(isGroupStart) over (order by tranid) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   (case when supplyType = 'A'
                         then 0
                         when lag(supplyType) over (order by tranid) = 'A'
                         then 1 
                         when datediff(day, lag(supplieddate) over (order by tranid), supplieddate) > 35
                         then 1
                         else 0
                    end) as isGroupStart
            from t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thanku Gordon. May I know why you are checking DateDiff greater than 35 days?

Comment: @DevMJ . . . "one month" seems rather nebulous.  That seems like a safe cutoff.